# read mdb file with PDO in Debian returns "segmentation fault" error

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc

I am trying to read an mdb file with PDO but I get "segmentation fault" error.

So far now what I did:
- installed php-odbc driver
- set correctly "/etc/odbcinst.ini" file
- connected to mdb file with PDO
- read some tables.

I can read some data from the mdb file without errors, but I do not know why sometimes I get "`segmentation fault`" error.

```
try {
    $db = storage_path("import/mdb/" . $this->argument('file'));
    if(!file_exists($db)) {
        die('Error finding access database');
    }
    // Connection to ms access
    $conn = new \PDO("odbc:Driver=MDBTools;DBQ=$db", "", "");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(); // IT WORKS

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(); // IT DOES NOT WORK

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (\Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: Edit question to show example data that causes failure.

Comment: Do you mean the data in the mdb file or the structure of the table that causes failure?

Comment: What values are being processed when the code fails? Is Table_1 just a copy of Table? Why would you pull same records into 2 queries?

Comment: They are 2 different tables. One of them fails. I need to read these 2 tables and insert in a mysql database.